# What do the terms "clunkers" and "keepers" mean when referring to a TV shows?

Tags: plot-explanation

I often hear about a TV season having both **clunkers and keepers.**

What does it mean?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about English language.

Comment: Then delete this Keen. I can't delete it.

Comment: Clunkers are the bad episodes and keepers are the good ones. (In case this stays closed at least you get an answer.)

Answer (score 5):

A "clunker" is used to describe something that's broken, originally as in a car that is often broken-down.

A "keeper", on the other hand, refers to something worth keeping, or the opposite of a clunker.

Comment: While one could infer your answer to the OP, can you edit to be more explicit in the context of TV shows